# How to pass value from form to url parameter

Tags: webforms

in my sidebar i have block with a form where users add name of restaurant and when they cick Submit they are supposed to be redirected to a page where my webform is.

I need url like this /add-your-restaurant?key=value-from-text-field but im not sure how to pass that value in url with my form.

I have already %get[key] as default value for my Name field in webform.

This is my html form:

```
<form name="addres" id="addres" method="post" action="">
<span>
<input type="text" name="addresfield" class="resfield" value="Enter your Restaurant name"/>
</span>
<input type="button" class="btn"/>
</form>
```

Comment: this is not Drupal question, its normal html question. change `method="post"` to `method="get"`

Comment: How are you building the form-in-the-lock?  Manual HTML or Forms API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution and working form as desired.

```
<form name="addres" id="addres" method="get" action="add-your-restaurant">
 <span><input type="text" name="addresfield" class="resfield"
 name="key" value="Enter your Restaurant name"/></span>
<input type="submit" class="btn"/>
</form>
```